# How to use whitespaces in feature names in Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, automated-tests, whitespace, gherkin

I am using Windows and trying to run an existing feature pack which was initially built on Mac OS which allows them to get around the issue with using `" \ "` with the whitespace.

I am using Ruby 2.2.3 and Cucumber.

The feature names contain white spaces and I am unable to change this. I tried to use `" "` and `' '` to get around the white spaces but have the same issue each time.

Here is an example of the issue.  If I run:

```
cucumber features/'Name containing whitespaces.feature'
```

it works OK.

But when I run:

```
cucumber -p my_profile
```

and cucumber.yml contains:

```
my_profile: features/'Name containing whitespaces.feature'
```

Then it fails with:

```
No such file or directory - features/'Name. You can use `cucumber --init` to get started.
```

Can anyone help me get round this issue as renaming is not an option in my case.

Comment: https://cucumber.io/pro might help more. also reporting this as an issue https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber might help too. i'm trying to repro locally. what version of cucumber were you using?

Comment: Sounds like a Windows white space problem. Is it still the case that you need a backslash to separate directories in windows? If so you have to add that as well.Did you try putting the entire path+name between double quotes: "features\name containing whitespaces.feature".

Answer (score 0):

You can test specific features using Cucumber's @ tags. I like using @wip, which stand for work in progress. For Example

In login.feature

```
Feature: Log in
  @wip
  Scenario: Successful Login
     Given I do some things
     Then I should be logged in
```

Then in the terminal you would run

```
cucumber --tags @wip
```

and it will only  run the tests under that scenario or feature.

This will allow you to test specific features or scenarios in cucumber without having to worry about the whitespacing in the names.